# Differences between assoc-in with two elements and update / assoc

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, hashmap

I've been doing for a while things like `(assoc-in my-hash [:data :id] 1)`, and it looks fine.

Recently, since I rarely have more than two levels, I noticed I can do `(update my-hash :data assoc :id 1)`, which sounds totally different, but returns the same.

So, I wonder, is there any difference in performance? Do you think it's more readable in one way than the other? More idiomatic?

`update / assoc` feels like it's more expensive to me, but I really like it better than `assoc-in`, which makes me stop to think each time I see it.

Comment: `assoc-in` is much more readable IMO.  You see that you are associating a value in a map, and the path to it is `:data`, then `:id`  -- simple, easy to read.  Also, consider that the function `assoc-in` is intended for this very purpose; using functions for their intended purposes means that usually the code is clearer, and also that the common vocabulary of the core library is clear to anyone else reading it.  Unless this is done more than 100000 times every second (in which case you'd be using transients anyway), I wouldn't worry about it being slower at all.

Comment: Exactly, looks like everyone uses `assoc-in`, but `update` is kind of new (added on 1.8.0, I think), so it could have open a new way of doing it, but yeah, I'll keep `assoc-in` :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it comes to performance, it's always good to measure. Ideally you'd assemble a realistic map (whether your maps are big or small will have some impact on the relative cost of various operations) and try it both ways with [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium):

```
(require '[criterium.core :as c])

(let [m (construct-your-map)]
  (c/bench (assoc-in m [:data :id] 1))
  (c/bench (update m :data assoc :id 1)))
```

Under the hood, `update` + `assoc` is sort of the unrolled version of `assoc-in` here that doesn't need the auxiliary vector to hold the keys, so I would expect it to be faster than `assoc-in`. But (1) ordinarily I wouldn't worry about minor performance differences when it comes to things like this, (2) when I do care, again, it's better to measure than to guess.

*(On my box, with Clojure 1.9.0-alpha14, `update` + `assoc` is indeed faster at ~282 ns vs ~353 ns for `assoc-in` given my small test map of `(assoc (into {} (map #(vector % %)) (range 20)) :data {:id 0})`.)*

Ultimately most of the time readability will be the more important factor, but I don't think you can say in general than one approach is more readable than the other. If you have a `→` chain that already uses `assoc-in` or `update` multiple times, it may be preferable to repeat the same function for the sake of consistency (just to avoid making the reader wonder "is this thing really different"). If you have a codebase that you control, you can adopt a "house style" that favours one approach over the other. Etc., etc.

I might see `assoc-in` as a little more readable most of the time – it uses a single "verb" and makes it clear at a glance what the (single, exact) path to the update is – but if you prefer `update` + `assoc` and expect to keep their use consistent in your codebase, that's certainly fine as well.

Comment: Another minor difference (advantage) of `update(-in)/assoc` over `assoc-in` is, that you can assoc multiple k/v-s at once.

Comment: @cfrick Indeed! There's a ticket in JIRA for support for multiple key/value pairs in `assoc-in` – [CLJ-1771](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1771). It was posted quite a while ago and lay mostly dormant since, but it seems there is some interest now (it's been prescreened by Alex Miller recently).

Comment: Right, I think the performance is not really a big deal, just wanted to see other people's views on this. I agree that `assoc-in` could be the "normal" way, maybe I just stick to `assoc-in` and get used to it. Thank you! :)